# Trying to get a scoreboard to update - Java

Tags: java, listener

I'm working on a Tetris project for school, I've stumbled on to a problem when trying to get a scorboard to update when my score is increased. As of now it adds the score when I start the game but the listener won't update when the score is increased. I'm working on another java project simultaneously with a friend where we have a asimilar methood working, but even though i've tried to copy the functions from that project i can't get it to update.

Score function:

```
private void scoreKeeper(int n) {
    switch (n) {
        case 1:
            score += 100;
            break;
        case 2:
            score += 300;
            break;
        case 3:
            score += 500;
            break;
        case 4:
            score += 800;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public int getScore() {
    System.out.println(score);
    return score;
}
```

And framework:

```
class TetrisFrame extends JFrame implements BoardListener {

private Board board;
JLabel scoreLabel;

@Override public void boardChanged() {
        scoreLabel.setText("Score: " + board.getScore());
    }

public TetrisFrame(Board board) {
    super("Tetris");
    this.board = board;
    JButton close = new JButton("Exit");
    this.scoreLabel = new JLabel("Score: " + board.getScore());
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    final TetrisComponent frame = new TetrisComponent(board);

    JComponent.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);

    this.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    menuBar.add(close);
    menuBar.add(scoreLabel);

    close.addActionListener(e -> {
        int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do You want to close the game?\n" + "All progress will be lost!",
                "Exit game", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.add(frame, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    this.pack();
    this.setSize(frame.getPreferredX(board), frame.getPreferredY(board));
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setFocusable(true);
    frame.requestFocusInWindow();

    }
}
```

Function that updates scoreboard:

```
private void checkForFullLine() {
    boolean fullLine = false;

    for (int h = 1; h < getHeight() - 1 ; h++) {
        for (int w = 1; w < getWidth() - 1; w++) {
            if (getSquares(w, h) == SquareType.EMPTY) {
                fullLine = false;
                break;
            }
            fullLine = true;

        }
        if (fullLine) {
            amountOfFullLines += 1;
            clearRow(h);
            moveBoardDown(h);
        }
    }
    scoreKeeper(amountOfFullLines);
    amountOfFullLines = 0;
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: Where is the code that updates the scoreboard? You've showed everything other than that.

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry :) there now

Comment: corrected my answer to fit the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on EDT you can simply call from checkForFullLine()

```
boardChanged()
```

otherwise you can invoke GUI update with SwingUtilities.invokeLater since you're not allowed to directly change GUI from other threads:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        boardChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have a notifyListeners() function wich does that, I've tried adding it to scoreKeeper without any results :/

Comment: oh wait, you said checkForFullLine(), well tried it but same result.

Comment: There is something else probably wrong there. Also you never add tetris frame as listener to board so there is no way to notify it. at least not in code provided.